# Mix of distinctUntilChanged() and throttle(_ dueTime: RxTimeInterval, latest: Bool = true, scheduler: SchedulerType) methods

Tags: ios, rx-swift

Is it possible to prepare mechanism in RXSwift which works like mix between
`func distinctUntilChanged()` and `func throttle(_ dueTime: RxTimeInterval, latest: Bool = true, scheduler: SchedulerType)`.

Lets assume there are many signals being emitted to the subscription like:
A, B, C, D, B, D, A, X, C, Z ...
and lets assume I want to pass only once signal which occurrences can take place multiple times in specified timespan. In practise it means that if I specify timespan as 5s and signal with value A takes place 3 times during this timespan I will only pass this signal once and after timespan passed this mechanizm is being reset and continuous working in the manner. Obviously timespan starts when first occurrence of signal A takes place. In meantime all other signals (D, C, ...) works in the same approach.

Let me know if this is feasible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely something very much like this will do what you want:

```
func example<T>(scheduler: SchedulerType, dueTime: RxTimeInterval, source: Observable<T>) -> Observable<T> where T: Hashable {
    source.groupBy(keySelector: { $0 })
        .flatMap { $0.throttle(dueTime, latest: false, scheduler: scheduler) }
}
```

Here are some tests and their results:

```
final class ExampleTests: XCTestCase {
    // at three seconds, everything gets through
    func testAt3() {
        let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
        let source = scheduler.createObservable(timeline: "A-B-C-D-B-D-A-X-C-Z")
        let expected = parseEventsAndTimes(timeline:      "A-B-C-D-B-D-A-X-C-Z", values: { String($0) })
            .offsetTime(by: 200)[0]
        let result = scheduler.start {
            example(scheduler: scheduler, dueTime: .seconds(3), source: source)
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(result.events, expected)
    }

    // at five seconds, the extra D is stopped
    func testAt5() {
        let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
        let source = scheduler.createObservable(timeline: "A-B-C-D-B-D-A-X-C-Z")
        let expected = parseEventsAndTimes(timeline:      "A-B-C-D-B---A-X-C-Z", values: { String($0) })
            .offsetTime(by: 200)[0]
        let result = scheduler.start {
            example(scheduler: scheduler, dueTime: .seconds(5), source: source)
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(result.events, expected)
    }

    // at seven seconds, the extra B and D are both stopped.
    func testAt7() {
        let scheduler = TestScheduler(initialClock: 0)
        let source = scheduler.createObservable(timeline: "A-B-C-D-B-D-A-X-C-Z")
        let expected = parseEventsAndTimes(timeline:      "A-B-C-D-----A-X-C-Z", values: { String($0) })
            .offsetTime(by: 200)[0]
        let result = scheduler.start {
            example(scheduler: scheduler, dueTime: .seconds(7), source: source)
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(result.events, expected)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel, that really seems to be working when I tried it out with my use case. Regarding tests - can you share your implementation of **TestScheduler** extension? I found implementation here https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/main/RxExample/RxExample-iOSTests/TestScheduler+MarbleTests.swift, but this code seems to be outdated for latest **TestScheduler** class implementation as compilers complains about not existing **resolution** attribute on the **TestScheduler** class.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/danielt1263/bd449100764e3166644f7a38bca86c96

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your help. One more question- why is this offset needed `offsetTime(by: 200)` ?

Comment: By default, the `start` method in a TestScheduler will create the observables at time 100, start them at 200 and dispose them at 1000. I could have explicitly told the start method different times, but advancing the expected result seems easier to me.